# Android mapping does not work

Tags: android, hashmap

Hi I have to send map to server and the server will get information from that. I'm having two piece of code for mapping first is(name and key are variables)

```
String user = "{ 'id':" + userId +","+"'response':{'id':"+userId+",'access':"+"'"+name+":"+key+"'"+"}}";

        Map<String, Object> userMap = new Gson().fromJson(user, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
        Set<String> keys = userMap.keySet();
        for (String i:keys){
            Log.d("user",i+"  "+userMap.get(i));
        }
```

here I concat required string and parse it and then convert it into map . This piece of code had worked. And my second set of code is

```
String user1 = "{id="+userId+", access="+""+name+":"+key+""+"}";
        Map<String,Object> tuc = new HashMap<>();
        tuc.put("id",userId);
        tuc.put("access","");
        Set<String> key = tuc.keySet();
        for (String i:key){
            Log.d("user",i+"  "+tuc.get(i));
        }
```

this code is not working,that mean server is not accepting this code. But when I print key value pairs the results are same for both codes. My lead doesn't like to use first piece of code. Can any one explain why,I'm struck in this for past two days. Thank you.Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, HashMap can only accept `<key, value>` pairs. It is not like Json, which in your case is in `{key1:value1, key2:value2, ...}` format.

Therefore, if you are intended to convert its format from `{key1:value1, key2:value2, ...}` into `<key, value>`. My suggestion is combining `value2, value3, ...` into an object (like `String`) as the value and `value1` as the key.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html for more details.

Comment: Thank you but this is not working , because it will get userId from key value "id".It is very essential to mention "id" and "access" as keys

Comment: In server for the first code "access":{"id"..... it accepts but for the second code "access":"{"id".... you can see only difference is there is double quote after semi colon.

Comment: Sorry, I think I have misread a part of your code. Is my current answer correct?